# Check if substring in string, and make string's chars uppercase (when found a substring there

Tags: c

**What I need to write:**

> 1.Get a main string from user.
>
> 2.Get a subString from a user.
>
> 3. Every match of the subString in the main string, change its letters to uppercase.
> 4. Do not use string's functions like strstr.

**For example:**

> main string:  abcdeffghfhkfff
>
> sub string: ff
>
> outut: abcdeFFghfhkFFf

**Problem:** Well, I'm having troubles to continue writing the code after I found one match. for example after I found the first 'f' in the main string, how can I continue check if the second 'f' is adjacent to the found 'f', if not, then try to find another 'f' and check subsequent matches of the subarray until we've found that the length of the substring matches the number of subsequent matches in the string?  Here's what I've tried, and in writing the logic of the for loop in 'replaceSubstring' function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 101
void replaceSubstring(char *str, char *subStr);

void main()
{
    char str[N], subStr[N];
    while (strlen(str) != 0 || strlen(subStr) != 0)

    {
        str[0] = 0;
        printf("Enter text: ");
        gets(str);
        printf("Enter substring: ");
        scanf("%s", subStr);

        replaceSubstring(str, subStr);

    }
}

void replaceSubstring(char *str, char *SubStr)
{
    int  i, count = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == SubStr[k])
        {
            k++;
            count++;
            if (count == strlen(SubStr))
            {
                str[i] -= 32;
            }
            

        }
    }
    puts(str);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: You forgot to reset `k = 0` after a mismatch, and after the success.

Comment: Aside: `for (i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++)` iterates too far, `for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)`

Comment: Try separating the problem into smaller ones. For example: can SubSring of size Len be found in String starting at position Pos? Change the case of L letters in String starting from position Pos.

Comment: The main thing to realize is that you have to first search for a first character match and then check for the match of the rest of the string. Use a second set of counters for matching the rest of the string so that you don't loose your position in the main string. To clarify the process you could even use a second function for matching the rest of the string and capitalization

Comment: Thanks to your comments. I've upgraded my code. @WeatherVane

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS I rolled back the question. Please don't remove errors from the question (unless the question was incorrectly asked). It makes the original question, comments and answer, very hard to understand without looking back through the edits.

Comment: @Ilan Aizelman WS Why accept an answer that uses `strstr()` if "Do not use string's functions like strstr."?

Comment: Because it is easy doing so with strstr(), but I don't know if someone will help me with my code anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strstr()` function to do this more easly, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 101
void replaceSubstring(char *str, char *subStr);

void main()
{
    char str[N], subStr[N];
    while (strlen(str) != 0 || strlen(subStr) != 0)

    {
        str[0] = 0;
        printf("Enter text: ");
        gets(str);
        printf("Enter substring: ");
        scanf("%s", subStr);

        replaceSubstring(str, subStr);

    }
}

void replaceSubstring(char *str, char *SubStr)
{
    int  i;
    char *tmp;

    while((tmp = strstr(str, SubStr)) != NULL)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(SubStr); i++)
        {        
            tmp[i] -= 32;
        }
    }
    puts(str);
    getchar();
}
```

Here another version of `replaceSubstring()` function without using `strstr()` function:

```
void replaceSubstring(char *str, char *SubStr)
{
    int  i = 0, found = 1, j = 0, k = 0;

    while (i < strlen(str))
    {    
        if (str[i] == SubStr[0])
        {
            found = 1;            
            for(k = 0; k < strlen(SubStr); k++)
            {
                if(str[i+k] != SubStr[k])
                {
                    found = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(found)
            {
                for(k = 0; k < strlen(SubStr); k++)
                {
                    str[i+k] -= 32;
                }
                i += strlen(SubStr);
            }
            else
                i++;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    puts(str);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Although I did wanted to get my code working without strstr.

Comment: I have updated my response, I have added a new version of `replaceSubstring()` function without using `strstr()` function.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this without using `strstr()`, i would do something like this:

```
void replaceSubstring(char *str, char *SubStr)
{
    int  i = 0, equals = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){
        j = i;
        equals = 1;
        k=0;
        while(k<strlen(SubStr)&&(equals == 1)){
            if(SubStr[k] != str[j]){
                equals = 0;
            }
            k++;
            j++;
        }
        if(equals == 1){
            for(j=i;j<i+k;j++){
                str[j] -= 32;
            }
        }
    }
    puts(str);
    getchar();
}
```

I'm pretty sure this works correctly.

```
input: abcdeffghfhkfff
substring: ff
output: abcdeFFghfhkFFf
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be written

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * replaceSubstring( char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    char *p = s1;
    size_t n = strlen( s2 );

    while ( ( p = strstr( p, s2 ) ) != NULL )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i, ++p  ) *p = toupper( ( unsigned char )*p );     
    }

    return s1;
}

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "abcdeffghfhkfff";

    puts( s );
    puts( replaceSubstring( s, "ff" ) );
}
```

Its output is

```
abcdeffghfhkfff
abcdeFFghfhkFFf
```

Take into account that according to the C Standard function main without parameters shall be declared like`

```
int main( void )
```

Also it is a bad idea to use "magic" numbers like 32 like in this statement

```
tmp[i] -= 32;
```

For example if in the environment there are used EBCDIC characters then this statement will be simply wrong.

Moreover even for ASCII characters this statement is invalid because it is not necessary that original characters are in lower case.